# Add variables in text elements

Tags: svg

Dynamically generate text in svg file

I want to build a svg file that displays some variables like the used browser on click. There is the `<text> </text>` element but I have no idea if there is a way to add dynamic text based on variables. In my example the text "dog" is static.

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
<text x="50" y="50">dog</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Could you share details regarding how you want to use this svg ? If it's in a framework like react/angular, you could wrap the svg in a component and pass the dynamic text from the parent using templates.

Comment: I just want to use a plain svg image without any frameworks. It is possible to reference to a external text file in the same folder?